# Constants middleware for user-facing strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm new to node.js and express.

I'm building an app that uses ejs and I'd like to have a `constants` file for user-facing strings so in the .ejs files I can use

`<%= constants.WELCOME %>` to display a welcome message.

I believe I can define locals in my `app.js` file as such:

`app.locals.WELCOME = "Hi and welcome to my app";`

but that will get cumbersome quickly.

I'd like to have a constants.js file:

```
module.exports = {
     WELCOME: 'Hi and welcome to my app",
     ENTER_USERNAME: "Please enter your username",
     etc.
}
```

but I'm not sure how to define a middleware function `app.use( <?> )` that lets me access my constants from anywhere.

1. Am I thinking about this correctly or is there a better way to implement?
2. How can set up the constants file and use it as middleware?  Would this even count as middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a middleware unless something is specific to the request or response (e.g. if you want to internationalize as @zero298 suggests).  If you just want a file of constants available, you can just do:

```
app.locals = require('./path/to/constants.js');
```

and then define constants.js the way you asked to.

If you really want a middleware, the signature is:

```
module.exports = function(req,res,next){
  // however you want to manipulate the req or res
  return next();
}
```

and then:

```
app.use(yourMiddleware);
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Now I can access the constants like this `<%= HI %>`.  Thanks for the middleware signature too, I'm sure that will come in handy soon.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like i18n. It's mostly used for internationalizing language in an application, but has the added benefit of centralizing string constants. It also plays well or has bindings for many popular JS frameworks.

Comment: It still takes magic strings as input to the __ function, which I think is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Paul Maybe I'm wrong, but the point I was mainly addressing was "that lets me access my constants from anywhere."

Comment: That's fair, I guess we'll see what he says. My thought was that the API for i18ln still takes a string to access whatever your output value will be, so it just creates a different constant in this case.  While it would definitely be a shorter constant, and of course is of benefit in multilingual scenarios, it wasn't addressing what I'd thought his main concern was.  But like I said, we'll see.  i18ln is still important and a good suggestion.

Comment: Right now I just needed Paul's answer.  I'll check out i18n.  It sounds good but I have a LOT to wrap my head around right now.  Thanks!